# Keep phone area code in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achieve is the input type text with initial area code added as a value

```
<input type="text" value="+1" id="phone" name="phone">
```

when user starts adding his/her phone number - this first +1 remains. 
Here is how I have solved this:

```
$('#phone').keyup( function(){


  var phone = $('#phone').val().substr(3); // copy phone number without the code
  $('#phone').val(''); // emptying the value
  $('#phone').val('+1-'+ phone); // adding the area code + entered number

});
```

but I guess it is rather silly and could be way better.
Here is Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gjzv6aph/

How can I make it better?

Comment: ups, sorry  - yea. corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) method with a callback function to generate new value with old value, the callback holds index as the first argument and old value as the second argument.

```
$('#phone').val(function(i, v){ 
  return '+1-' + v.substr(3); 
});
```

```js
$('#phone').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return '+1-' + v.substr(3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" value="+1-">
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pranav. Definitely - this is much better

Comment: a `$(this)` would not hurt ;) also why are you suggesting `keyup`, what if I **paste**-in some value? Can you do better?

Comment: I have a solution for pasting...also replacing all non digits... the only doubt was with this particular task - to keep the area code initially and during the phone number entering. .

Comment: @Rossitten : use input event